# Netsuite search script logs by user

Tags: search, logging, netsuite

Is there a way to create a custom script log search (view) in Netsuite that filters out all logs by a certain user?

I have tried joining on User Fields : Internal ID, Internal ID (number), First Name, Last Name, Name/ID, and email, but none of these seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to filter execution logs by user, you go to 'customize view' to create a new search and use the criteria 'user', with no joins, only 'user'. Then you can filter by 'user IS [username]'. Make sure to type the exact name of the user, otherwises it won't work.